# Transform strings (from a pandas dataframe column that also contains integers) into integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that contains integers and strings.

I want to keep the integers and convert only the strings of that column into integers using the `int.from_bytes` method. Is this possible?

Any other way you would suggest?

I need to always transform any string that appears in this column (usually max 3 character strings) into the same unique integer. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Apologies for the late reply and the confusing question. I did in fact try various things that did not work, but definitely my question was not clear enough. To illustrate the problem, first consider that you can transform a string of characters into an integer using the following code:

```
int.from_bytes(bytearray('CD', 'ascii'), byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

where 'CD' is the string I want to transform into an integer. In this case 'CD' is transformed to the int 17220. 'C2' for example will be transformed to 17202.

In my case, I have a column containing integers and strings. The strings are usually 2 or 3 character strings such as the ones mentioned above. I want to transform this column, keeping the integers as is, and transforming the strings into integers with the method above. So for example a column [1, 'CD', 2, 'C2'] should be transformed to [1, 17220, 2, 17202].

From @AlexanderMcFarlane 's answer I managed to find a solution like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"[-+]?\d+(\.0*)?$")

def is_int(v):
    return regex.match(str(v).strip()) is not None  

def string_int(x):
    if is_int(x):
        return int(float(x))
    else:
        return int.from_bytes(bytearray(x, 'ascii'), byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
x = [1, 'CD', 2, 'C2', '5']
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col'])

In: df
Out:     col
     0   1
     1   CD
     2   2
     3   C2
     4   5  

In: df['col']=df['col'].apply(string_int)
    df  
Out:     col
     0   1
     1   17220
     2   2
     3   17202
     4   5
```

I would appreciate your feedback. And many thanks to @AlexanderMcFarlane

Comment: Sample data, output, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show us your effort! SO is not a coding service but we are 'all' willing to help. And post an example of what you have and what you want in the end so we get a better understanding of the problem. Then you might get the answer you wished for.

Comment: @MarvinTaschenberger I think it's quite obvious

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"[-+]?\d+(\.0*)?$")

def is_int(v):
    return regex.match(str(v).strip()) is not None

def safe_int(x):
    if is_int(x):
        return int(float(x))
    else:
        return x
```

Then operate on

```
df[column] = df[column].apply(safe_int)
```

## Example

```
In [17]: map(safe_int, ['1.0', '1', 's', '23546.fdf'])
Out[17]: [1, 1, 's', '23546.fdf']
```

Comment: I use this exact logic every single day to transform millions of strings to integers - the downvote isn't therefore a reflection on the correctness

Comment: My guess is the downvoter didn't like the assumptions in your answer. For instance, that there are strings that cannot be converted to integers in the column, or that OP would like to retain those invalid strings as strings in the column (which are details currently impossible to determine based on OP's question ambiguity). Because should those assumptions not be the case, they might get away with something far simpler.

Comment: Yeah no worries I just wanted to clarify this is the absolute foolproof method of conversion and saw an opportunity to showcase my baby and help someone :)

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Thank you for your answer. Due to the ambiguity of my question, your code was not exactly what I wanted, but it helped me to come up with a solution, although I'm not sure it's the most efficient one, pls see above.